# PHP: How to style session output

Tags: php, css, session, styles

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
    Welcome, <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?>
    <br>
    <a href='mcLogout.php'>Logout</a>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <p class="da">Don't have an account?</p>
    <p><a class="lr" href='registrationpage.php'>Register Here</a></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

The code is display the username of the user who is in the session (logged) and a link to log out. I wish to know how can I give a style to the username using CSS i.e:

```
"Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['username']?>"
```

This part of the code.

Comment: perhaps you can put the username in <div> and then style it using css.

Comment: can you insert html in the [''] of the session then?

Comment: you can just echo the variable in php tag in the html tag. For an example `<div><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ever comes between  wihle echoing are just like any other HTML element.

```
<h1>" Welcome, " <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?></h1>
```

or

```
Welcome, <h1 class="username"><?= $_SESSION['username'] ?></h1>
```

Comment: just a small footnote, make sure that your server setting allows short php tag <? ?> otherwise to be safe you can use <?php ?>

Answer (score 1):

you could just wrap it in `<span>` and do some CSS, like:

```
...
Welcome, <span class="username"><?=$_SESSION['username']?></span>
...
```

then css:

```
.username {
    color: #D2D8D9;
    font-weight: bold;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your "Welcome part in a div"

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
    <div class="welcome-user">Welcome, <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?></div>
    <br>
    <a href='mcLogout.php'>Logout</a>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <p class="da">Don't have an account?</p>
    <p><a class="lr" href='registrationpage.php'>Register Here</a></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't have short tags `<? ... ?>` Turned on... I think... 
Try `<?php ... ?>` this will do... and instead of `<?=$_SESSION['username']; ?>` write `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` 
This will work...